# show stdout and stderr in richtextbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

If I have a GUI like this:

```
---------------------

[Button]

---------------------
[RichTextbox_output]

---------------------
```

Would it be possible to show all:

stdout and stderr in the richTextbox that I can see from 'output' diaglog of visual studio?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By output, do you mean what you write to `Console.WriteLine` for stdout and `Console.Error.WriteLine` for stderr, or where you thinking about some other output?

Comment: yes. you are right of using Console WL and Er

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stdout in C# is called `Console.Out`. Stderr is called `Console.Error`.

To solve this you will need to redirect `Console.Out`. This can be done using `Console.SetOut`. This will then need to be redirected to a custom stringwriter of your own that will write to the rich text box. This isn't built into the textbox and you will need to create a stream implementation of your own. One possible solution is to subclass `StringWriter` and overload the `WriteLine` method to push to your textbox instead.

```
public class TextBoxWriter : StringWriter
{
   public override void WriteLine(string x)
   {
       // Write to textbox here
   }
}
```

Obviously, if you use more than just `WriteLine` you'll have to create overloads for those methods as well.

The same approach can be taken with `Console.SetError` for the stderr stream.

Comment: This is the way to redirect .NET output.  If the .NET program calls native functions that use `stdout` and `stderr`, though, more work is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

For the stderr you'll have to encapsulate the program in a try/catch block.  Where you catch all the errors.  For the stdout there are two options, overwrite the stdout to write to the textbox or simply write to the textBox everywhere instead of writing to stdout.

For the exceptions:

```
try {
   // your program
catch (Exception e){
   RichTextbox_output.AppendText()
}
```

This example requires the RichTextbox be within scope though, so placement in the program might be tricky.

For every place where you use stdout, in place of Console.write, use RichTextbox_output.AppendText()